# DocuSign REST API - pause workflow + webhooks (node.js)

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusignconnect

Good afternoon,

I am integrating DocuSign into our business applications (node.js) and have an issue:

Is there a way to use the DocuSign connect webhook to let me know when a workflow is paused? On the admin connect page, I have all possible boxes checked on the connect options - which do not include anything about workflow status (mostly signed/delivered/completed/declined stuff).

My current workaround is to add a customField on the Signer 'pauseAfterSigned' which I check for in the webhook xml. If the signer with that field has Status "Completed" then I know the workflow has been paused. This seems like a lousy workaround :(

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't have an event fired when a workflow is paused as far as I know. So your workaround would have to do for now. Can you please provide more information around your scenario? Perhaps it's something we should consider adding depending on the scenario here. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for responding :)
So we have a few Signatures from various departments (sales, customer, etc), then we pause, then upon resume we have one final signature from the CEO.
We have a UI for our business team for generating and managing contracts, and during the pause we want our business apps to add some of the envelope data (pdfs, signatories) into our database and prompt our business team to review the envelope/contract within our application. Once they review and click accept, then we unpause the Docusign workflow.
Our business team deems it essential that this is handled in our ui.

Comment: Thank you, we will advocate for adding the paused events internally. Thank you again for raising this issue.